# Prove that the only zero-length vector is nil

Tags: coq, dependent-type

I have a type defined as

```
Inductive bits : nat -> Set :=
| bitsNil : bits 0
| bitsCons : forall {l}, bool -> bits l -> bits (S l).
```

and I'm trying to prove:

```
Lemma emptyIsAlwaysNil : forall {a: bits 0}, a = bitsNil.
```

After `intros`, I've tried `constructor 1`, `case a`, `intuition`, to no avail. `case a` seems like the closest, but it gets an error:

```
Abstracting over the terms "0" and "a" leads to a term
fun (n : nat) (a0 : bits n) => a0 = bitsNil
which is ill-typed.
Reason is: Illegal application: 
The term "@eq" of type "forall A : Type, A -> A -> Prop"
cannot be applied to the terms
 "bits n" : "Set"
 "a0" : "bits n"
 "bitsNil" : "bits 0"
The 3rd term has type "bits 0" which should be coercible to 
"bits n".
```

It sounds like it can't determine whether a bit-vector of an arbitrary length is equal to one of zero-length, because they're different at the type level. Is that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're basically correct: specifically, what isn't type checking is Coq's attempt to construct a `match` on `a:bits 0` (which is what `case` does): the `bitsCons` case has an ill-typed conclusion.

Here's an axiom-free proof. The key idea is to manually generalize the statement to any `n = 0` (I couldn't figure out how to do this with tactics; they all trip up on the dependency). The equality proof then makes the conclusion type check regardless of what `n` is, and we can dismiss the `bitsCons` case because we'll have `n = S n'`. In the more difficult `bitsNil` case, we make use of `eq_rect_eq_dec`, which is a consequence of Axiom K but is provable when the type index (`nat`, in this case) has decidable equality. See the [Coq standard library documentation](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Logic.Eqdep_dec.html) for some other things you can do without axioms with decidable equality.

```
Require PeanoNat.
Require Import Eqdep_dec.
Import EqNotations.

Inductive bits : nat -> Set :=
| bitsNil : bits 0
| bitsCons : forall {l}, bool -> bits l -> bits (S l).

Lemma emptyIsAlwaysNil_general :
  forall n (H: n = 0) {a: bits n},
    rew [bits] H in a = bitsNil.
Proof.
  intros.
  induction a; simpl.
  (* bitsNil *)
  rewrite <- eq_rect_eq_dec; auto.
  apply PeanoNat.Nat.eq_dec.
  (* bitsCons - derive a contradiction *)
  exfalso; discriminate H.
Qed.

Lemma emptyIsAlwaysNil : forall {a: bits 0},
    a = bitsNil.
Proof.
  intros.
  change a with (rew [bits] eq_refl in a).
  apply emptyIsAlwaysNil_general.
Qed.
```

You don't need the `rew H in x` notation from `EqNotations` (it just wraps `eq_rect`, the equality recursion principle), but I find it makes things much more readable.

However, you can prove this theorem more simply if you're willing to use an axiom, specifically `JMeq_eq` (see [CPDT's equality chapter](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Equality.html) for more details), since then you can use `dependent induction` or `dependent destruction`:

```
Require Import Program.Equality.

Inductive bits : nat -> Set :=
| bitsNil : bits 0
| bitsCons : forall {l}, bool -> bits l -> bits (S l).

Lemma emptyIsAlwaysNil :
  forall {a: bits 0}, a = bitsNil.
Proof.
  intros.
  dependent destruction a; reflexivity.
Qed.

Print Assumptions emptyIsAlwaysNil.
(* Axioms:
JMeq_eq : forall (A : Type) (x y : A), x ~= y -> x = y *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple proof (borrowed from [this Coq Club thread](http://coq-club.inria.narkive.com/wrDwvaNY/how-to-prove-that-all-vectors-of-0-length-are-equal-to-vector-nil)):

```
Definition emptyIsAlwaysNil {a: bits 0} : a = bitsNil :=
  match a with bitsNil => eq_refl end.

Opaque emptyIsAlwaysNil.
```

Here is what Coq builds under the hood:

```
Print emptyIsAlwaysNil.

emptyIsAlwaysNil = 
fun a : bits 0 =>
match
  a as a0 in (bits n)
  return
    (match n as x return (bits x -> Type) with
     | 0 => fun a1 : bits 0 => a1 = bitsNil
     | S n0 => fun _ : bits (S n0) => IDProp
     end a0)
with
| bitsNil => eq_refl
| bitsCons _ _ => idProp
end
     : forall a : bits 0, a = bitsNil
```

Comment: Reminds me of Monin's small inversions: https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/inria-00489412/