# Coq: Use equality of types for type checking a term in a definition

Tags: casting, coq, typechecking, dependent-type

I have a question regarding type checking definitions in Coq. I ran into a situation where I have two terms of type t1 and t2, where I know that t1 and t2 are equal (t1 = t2) from the definition. However, I cannot use those two terms together since the types are not considered equal by the type checker. I tried to isolate a minimum example modeling the situation (yeah I know that's a stupid property, but I just want it to get type checked ;) ):

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.

Lemma myLemma :
  forall t1 t2 : Type,
    forall (l1 : list t1) (l2 : list t2),
      t1 = t2 ->
        l1 = l2.
```

Just assume that I cannot write `(l2 : list t1)` directly instead, since I get it from another definition.

I tried using `Program` because I hoped that I could somehow defer the task to prove that the types match, but that did not help (got the same type checking errors).

---

If the example above is not sufficient for making the problem clear, here's an excerpt from my actual problem:

```
Definition taclet_sound_new (t : taclet) :=
  forall K st seSt, let S := (sig K) in
    [(K, st)] |= (pathC seSt) ->
      (forall K', let S' := (sig K') in
        S' = (newSig t S) ->
          exists (seSt' : (@sestatesc (newSig t S))),
            List.In seSt' (apply t S seSt) ->
              [(K', st)] |= (conv S' (pathC seSt'))).
```

The system complains that `The term "pathC seSt'" has type "@pathCond (newSig t S)" while it is expected to have type "@pathCond S'".`; however, from the premise `S' = (newSig t S)` I would expect that it somehow should be possible to get that definition type checked.

*(Remark: `conv` is a trivial definition which I only added for improving Coq's output -- `Definition conv (S : signature) (pc : (@pathCond S)) : list (@formulas S) := pc.` -- without that, it says `The term "pathC seSt'" has type "pathCond" while it is expected to have type "list formulas".` which hid the actual problem.)*

For completeness: The record `taclet` is defined as

```
Record taclet : Type := {
    defined (prog : P) : Prop;
    newSig (S1 : signature) : signature ;
    apply : forall (S1 : signature),
              (@sestatesc S1) -> list (@sestatesc (newSig S1)) ;
}.
```

So there is that `newSig` term in there. Therefore, the alternative definition

```
Definition taclet_sound_new (t : taclet) :=
  forall K st seSt, let S := (sig K) in
    [(K, st)] |= (pathC seSt) ->
      (forall K', let S' := (sig K') in
          exists (seSt' : (@sestatesc S')),
            S' = (newSig t S) ->
              List.In seSt' (apply t S seSt) ->
                [(K', st)] |= (pathC seSt')).
```

Also does not type check, with the similar error `The term "apply t S seSt" has type "list (sestatesc P (newSig t S))" while it is expected to have type "list (sestatesc P S')".` which, again, should be clear from the premise.

I would be very happy if anybody could help me out. That type checking mechanism of Coq is sometimes a little inconvenient... ;)

Thanks in advance!

---

**/edit (2018-09-27):** Although I gave myself an answer below that appeases the type checker, I still run into a lot of problems when trying to solve my problems around some theorems and definitions in the area of predicate logic. For instance, **I totally fail to define a satisfying version of a conservativity theorem** (if a formula is valid in a structure, it's also valid in all extensions) due to type checking, and **even if a add a crazy constraint** (the extension shares the same signature, so it's not really an extension) and add a (working) cast, **I cannot prove it**!

This time, I thought I give a **complete example**. I isolated the problem and put it into a single file "firstorder.v" as a **GitHub Gist** (https://gist.github.com/rindPHI/9c55346965418bd5db26bfa8404aa7fe). There are comments in the document explaining the challenges I discovered for myself. If anybody finds an answer to one or two of the "main challenges" in there, I'd be *really* happy to know about them (and would accept this as an answer to the question here). Thanks again! I hope that a solution to those problems not only helps me, but also others out there that are getting desperate due to dependent problems ;)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47981473/2747511) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47945424/2747511) are related.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the comment, the first link gave me the necessary input (writing a cast function; I tried that at an earlier point and failed, but now I got it work) -- see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment of Anton, I managed to resolve the issue in a way. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47982074/2787048) to the first question cited by Anton made me think about writing a `cast` function (I also tried to use the other alternative, JMeq, but it lead me nowhere -- probably I don't really understand it). I thought I'd share the solution, in case it helps somebody.

First, I wrote the following `cast` function and used it via two wrappers (which I won't post since they're not generally interesting:

```
Definition simple_cast {T1 T2 : Type} (H : T1 = T2) (x : T1) : T2 :=
  eq_rect T1 (fun T3 : Type => T3) x T2 H.
```

*(Remark: I did not directly come up with the* `eq_rect` *term, for that I'm not enough of a pro user; however, it's possible to do the following in Coq, which I find quite interesting:* `Definition simple_cast {T1 T2 : Type} (H : T1 = T2) (x : T1) : T2. rewrite -> H in x. assumption. Defined.` *If you then* `Print simple_cast`, *you get a term that you can simplify a bit and directly post into the definition to make it more explicit. Constructing the term that way is significantly easier since you can work with simple tactics).*

Next, I came up with the following definition which spared me the wrappers:

```
Definition cast {T : Type} {T1 T2 : T} (H : T1 = T2) (f : T -> Type) (x : f T1) :=
  eq_rect T1 (fun T3 : T => f T3) x T2 H.
```

Regarding the simple list example, the following code type checks:

```
Lemma myLemma :
  forall t1 t2 : Type,
    forall (l1 : list t1) (l2 : list t2),
      forall (H : t2 = t1),
        l1 = cast H (list) l2.
```

My actual code snippet also type checks:

```
  Definition taclet_sound_new (t : taclet) :=
    forall K st seSt, let S := (sig K) in
      [(K, st)] |= (pathC seSt) ->
        (forall K', let S' := (sig K') in
           forall (H : (newSig t S) = S'),
              exists (seSt' : (@sestatesc (newSig t S))),
                  List.In seSt' (apply t S seSt) ->
                    [(K', st)] |= (cast H (@pathCond) (pathC seSt'))).
```

Finally, I can cast expressions in Coq (given that there's named evidence that the cast is OK -- I can live with that)!

/edit: I now found a library for such casts: The [Heq library](https://people.mpi-sws.org/~gil/Heq/). With that, `myLemma` looks like

```
Lemma myLemma :
  forall t1 t2 : Type,
    forall (l1 : list t1) (l2 : list t2),
      forall (H : t2 = t1),
        l1 = << list # H >> l2.
```

so you don't have to write your own cast function.

Unfortunately, I couldn't really eliminate the casts in proofs (regardless of whether I use my own cast or the one of Heq); it seems that you need to be a really experienced dependent types hacker to do so. Or my lemmas are wrong, which I don't think however. For those of you who really want to get into the topic, there's a chapter on equalities in Adam Chlipala's great [CPDT book](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/); in my case, I'll personally just "`admit`" some proofs simplifying those expressions and build upon that. At least it type checks...

Comment: One way to write casts in an intuitive way without the use of the interactive mode is to use a `match` on the `H`. `simple _cast` then becomes `match H with |eq_refl => x end.`